# asterisk PAGI dynamic node interruptable

Tags: asterisk

im developing dialplan using asterisk and PAGI (PHP asterisk gateway interface)
but i cant find a way to create node which can have dynamic number of annoucements depends on result from database.
I found a way to do this by adding annoucements in loop in method called executeAfterRun
but when Im trying to interrupt node by pressing anything it interrupts only current annoucement and going to playing next one.
I want this whole node to be interruptable not just current annoucement.

can anyone help me with this problem ?
thanks in advance for any help
best regards

Answer (score 0):

You have create in your php code string like

```
announce1&announce2&announce3
```

using loop. After that you can use that string for Playback command, it will work like one large file.